# How to let discord bot send a message with auto detection of URL and show the Link preview as user?

Tags: discord.py

I made a discord bot that avaliable to send messages that basically doing copy & paste from a dialog.
When human user input a message with some URL, discord usually shows the preview like following picture:
[image]

My current code may (as shown as follow) allow my bot to send message however the preview of link seems not working.

```
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(message['ts'])).strftime('%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S')
text = fill_references(message['text'], users, channels)
msg = f"**{username}** *({timestamp})*\n{text}"
await ctx.send(msg)
```

[image]

Any idea how to slove this issue?

---

Role permission that bot using has Embed_Links avaliable.
[image]

Comment: The preview usually sends properly. Try `await ctx.send('https://google.com/')` and see if the auto embed shows up with that.

Comment: Thank you. 
I finally found the issue.
The message I grab from other place will automatic switch the URL to '<URL>' which will cause the preview stop working.